# what value type to be used to check/unchecked a checkbox in PDI ETL Metadata injection

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have `ETL Metadata Injection` steps which injects the meta data to the `CSV file input` step present in the template. I am able to inject all the meta data like File name to read , delimiter and field names and type of fields but I am not able to inject the meta for check box values like "`Header row present`"? or "`Running in parallel`"?

Question: what kind of values I should inject to make use of these check box's to be checked or unchecked dynamically??
is it

```
 1.) YES/NO 
 2.) yes/no
 3.) 1/0
 4.) enable/disable
 5.) true/false
 6.) TRUE/FALSE
```

[image]

Comment: I use `Y`/`N` in such case.

Comment: since my project is complex and complicate to test I can not do trail and error to test with all the possible combinations to find out the correct type. Since this is general doubt thought to post it SO as it might help others in future. I will check with these values and post my final results if I am successful. Thank you once agian

Comment: it's easy just check `Select values` step and see what it uses. You wont go wrong with their defaults.:)

Comment: I am sorry, but how 'Select values' step helps here...I really didn't understand...I have added image to my question...if you see 5th option HEADER_PRESENT they didn't mention about the type of value to be used...non of the examples and other SO threads or the video tutorials Metainjection examples never show which value type to be used

Comment: In `Select values` step, `Meta-data` tab, there are several column-names ending with '?' (most likely to ask `Yes`/`No` question), for example `Binary to Normal?`, just click the dropdown in any of the cell under such column, you will see what I mean.